# Creating new database under Oracle XE on Ubuntu

Tags: database, oracle, ubuntu, oracle-xe

I've just installed Oracle XE in Ubuntu. Is there any way to create new databases, besides the one that comes with the installation, preferably from the command line so that I can do it from a script? It would be nice to have multiple databases started in the same time, if possible.

If it is not possible to create new databases, then maybe there is a way to "clean up" the default database? What I need is to be able to "start over" at any time with a fresh database.

I don't have experience with Oracle administration, so any hints, links, suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't know if you are aware of this, but most beginners confuse this about Oracle:

In Oracle, a *database* means a collection of data files and control files stored on disk. You can have only one database with Oracle XE. A database is *mounted* by a Oracle *instance*, which means all the background daemons and programs that you can see with `ps`.

You probably want a *schema*, which is what other DBMS products (e.g. MySQL) often refer to as a "database". IIRC there was no limit on the number of schemas in Oracle XE. You can create those from the APEX UI that comes with XE, or from command line (with `CREATE USER` -- again, confusingly, a *user* and *schema* are largely synonymous in this case).

I recommend reading the *Concepts* guide from Oracle documentation, most of this basic stuff (e.g. how things are called in Oracle-lingo) is covered there.

Comment: You are right. I was not aware of the difference. I see that if I "CREATE USER ..." then I gen separate working contexts for each new user. This is what I needed. And if I "DROP USER ... CASCADE" then the user and its context are removed. Thanks!

Comment: actually, one can really create database in oracle, and let the XE instance to mount another database.

Answer (score 3):

No. It's not possible to install multiple XE instances. Oracle XE only allows one instance by machine from the [Oracle XE home page](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/index.html) you can read:

> *Oracle Database XE can be installed on any size host machine with any
>   number of CPUs  (**one database per machine**), but XE will store up to 4GB
>   of user data, use up to 1GB of memory, and use one CPU on the host machine.*

To add more instances you can:

- Use virtualization with an XE instace by virtual machine.
- Download for free dev/personal use any other [Oracle Database edition](http://www.oracle.com/database/product_editions.html), for instance [Oracle Standard Edition One](http://www.oracle.com/database/std_one.html).

Anyway, in most of the cases only one instance is enough for all the scenarios. Explain why do you need more instance to assistance about solutions.

To recreate the Xe instance, i thing the best and easy way is uninstall i and install again.